# Regrouping ordered ranges of dates

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to clean groups of periods on a table by comparing start and end dates with the previous ones to see if there is an equality.

An example is worth a thousand words:

| my key | start date | end date | tech date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-05-01 | 9999-12-31 | 2022-05-01 |
| A | 2023-01-01 | 9999-12-31 | 2023-01-01 |
| A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-05-01 | 2023-05-01 |
| A | 2023-07-01 | 9999-12-31 | 2023-07-01 |

I need to identify 2 periods as a result:

| my key | start date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-05-01 | 2023-05-01 |
| A | 2023-07-01 | 9999-12-31 |

One option I thought of was to "group" my data when start or end dates was the same than the previous row (ordered by the technical date):

| my key | start date | end date | tech date | group | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-05-01 | 9999-12-31 | 2022-05-01 | 1 | first group of key A |
| A | 2023-01-01 | 9999-12-31 | 2023-01-01 | 1 | same group as previous because end dates are equals |
| A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-05-01 | 2023-05-01 | 1 | same group as previous because start dates are equals |
| A | 2023-07-01 | 9999-12-31 | 2023-07-01 | 2 | new group because start and end dates are different from the previous row |

and then compute the start date as the smallest values of the group and end date as the largest value of the group (excluding 9999-12-31 when needed)

but I've trouble grouping the rows properly, I tried with analytical functions but I couldn't find a way to get the previous calculated group:

```
select mykey, startdate, enddate, techdate,
  case when lag(startdate,1,startdate) over (partition by mykey order by techdate) = startdate
       or lag(enddate,1,enddate) over (partition by mykey order by techdate) = enddate
    then lag(grp,1,grp) over (partition by mykey order by techdate)
    else grp
end as calc_grp
from (select mykey, startdate, enddate, techdate, row_number() over (partition by mykey order by techdate) as grp from mytable)
```

I tried some queries like this but of course, that doesn't work
I should use lag(calc_grp...) but that's not possible

Any idea to achieve this?

If that's not possible, I should be able to compute correct values with another approch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways this could be simplified. If you look at the intermediate cte results I'm sure you'll get some ideas.

The crux is identifying the period boundaries. So defining a binary period change condition indicator will get you something you can sum to get a period id.

Then it's just a matter of selecting the earliest start_date in the period by tech_date, and latest end_date by tech_date for each period. Lots of ways to skin that cat.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE my_temp_table (
    my_key VARCHAR(255),
    start_date DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    end_date DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    tech_date DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO my_temp_table (my_key, start_date, end_date, tech_date) VALUES ('A', DATE '2022-05-01', DATE '9999-12-31', DATE '2022-05-01');
INSERT INTO my_temp_table (my_key, start_date, end_date, tech_date) VALUES ('A', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '9999-12-31', DATE '2023-01-01');
INSERT INTO my_temp_table (my_key, start_date, end_date, tech_date) VALUES ('A', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-05-01', DATE '2023-05-01');
INSERT INTO my_temp_table (my_key, start_date, end_date, tech_date) VALUES ('A', DATE '2023-07-01', DATE '9999-12-31', DATE '2023-07-01');


with 
find_period_changes as (
select mtt.*,
       row_number() over ( partition by my_key order by tech_date ) as rn,
       case when coalesce(lag(start_date) over ( partition by my_key order by tech_date),date '1900-01-01') <> start_date
             and coalesce(lag(end_date) over ( partition by my_key order by tech_date),date '1900-01-01') <> end_date then 1 else 0 
        end as start_new_period
  from my_temp_table mtt),
group_periods as (
select a.*,
       sum(start_new_period) over ( partition by my_key
                                        order by tech_date
                                    rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as period_id
  from find_period_changes a),
start_and_end_rns as (
select my_key,
       period_id,
       min(rn) over ( partition by my_key,
                                   period_id) as period_start_rn,
       max(rn) over ( partition by my_key,
                                   period_id) as period_end_rn
  from group_periods)
select distinct
       sae.my_key,
       mtt_start_date.start_date,
       mtt_end_date.end_date
  from start_and_end_rns sae
 inner
  join find_period_changes mtt_start_date
    on sae.my_key = mtt_start_date.my_key
   and sae.period_start_rn = mtt_start_date.rn
 inner
  join find_period_changes mtt_end_date
    on sae.my_key = mtt_end_date.my_key
   and sae.period_end_rn = mtt_end_date.rn;
```

Comment: thank you, identifying boundaries first is a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using a `RECURSIVE CTE`. The example below is in MySQL 8.0, but you can alter the syntax/optimize the query to your needs.

**QUERY LOGIC:**

1. Use a `RECURSIVE CTE` to compare the ***current*** `START/END DATE` row values to the ***next*** `START/END DATE` row values.
2. If the current `START_DATE` or `END_DATE` match the next row values, then assign the same `DATE_GROUP` number. If they do not match, then increment the `DATE_GROUP` number by 1 (virtually assigning the non-matched row a new `DATE_GROUP`.
3. Return the ***first*** `START_DATE` value and the ***last*** `END_DATE` in the `DATE_GROUP`. Distinct to return unique values (I'm sure there is a better alternative to the distinct method, but I ran out of time).

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE date_periods (
  `my_key` VARCHAR(1),
  `start_date` DATETIME,
  `end_date` DATETIME,
  `tech_date` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO date_periods
  (`my_key`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `tech_date`)
VALUES
  ('A', '2022-05-01', '9999-12-31', '2022-05-01'),
  ('A', '2023-01-01', '9999-12-31', '2023-01-01'),
  ('A', '2023-01-01', '2023-05-01', '2023-05-01'),
  ('A', '2023-07-01', '9999-12-31', '2023-07-01');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_date_periods_recur (my_key, start_date, end_date, tech_date, row_num, date_group) AS
  (SELECT a.my_key,
          a.start_date,
          a.end_date,
          a.tech_date,
          a.row_num,
          1 AS date_group
   FROM
     (SELECT my_key,
             start_date,
             end_date,
             tech_date,
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY my_key
                                ORDER BY tech_date) AS ROW_NUM
      FROM date_periods) a
   WHERE a.ROW_NUM = 1
   UNION SELECT a.my_key,
                a.start_date,
                a.end_date,
                a.tech_date,
                a.row_num,
                CASE
                    WHEN a.start_date = b.start_date
                         OR a.end_date = b.end_date THEN b.date_group
                    ELSE b.date_group + 1
                END AS date_group
   FROM
     (SELECT my_key,
             start_date,
             end_date,
             tech_date,
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY my_key
                                ORDER BY tech_date) AS ROW_NUM
      FROM date_periods) a
   INNER JOIN cte_date_periods_recur b ON a.ROW_NUM = b.ROW_NUM + 1)
   
SELECT DISTINCT a.my_key,
                a.date_group,
                first_value(a.start_date) OVER(PARTITION BY a.my_key, a.date_group
                                               ORDER BY a.row_num) AS DATE_GROUP_START_DATE,
                first_value(a.end_date) OVER(PARTITION BY a.my_key, a.date_group
                                             ORDER BY a.row_num DESC) AS DATE_GROUP_END_DATE
FROM cte_date_periods_recur a;
```

| my_key | date_group | DATE_GROUP_START_DATE | DATE_GROUP_END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 |
| A | 2 | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)